# Approach for primary key generation

Tags: c#, sql-server

What is the best approach when generating a primary key for a table?

That is, when the data received by the database is not injective and can't be used as a primary key.

In the code, what is the best way to manage a primary key for the table rows?

Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand 'Injective'. What do you mean?

Comment: `injective function is a function that preserves distinctness`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First recommendation stay away from uniqueidentifier for any primary key.  Although it has some interesting easy ways to generate it client side, it makes it almost impossible to have any idexes on the primary key that may be useful.  If I could go back in time and ban uniqueidentifiers from 99% of the places that they have been used, this would have saved more than 3 man years of dba/development time in the last 2 years.

Here is what I would recommend, using the INT IDENTITY as a primary key.

```
create table YourTableName(
   pkID int not null identity primary key,
   ... the rest of the columns declared next.
)
```

where pkID is the name of your primary key column.

This should do what you are looking for.

Comment: Interesting. Could you extend your recommendation and explain why your expperiences with uniqueidentifiers are so bad. Why can't you have any useful indexes? Is that because of type size and indexes sizes?

Comment: With uniqueidentifiers in an index, they are extremely inefficient because there is no natural sort order.  Based on the b-tree structure of the index you end up with extremely fragmented indexes when using uniqueidentifiers.  After rebuilding or reorganizing, they are still extremely fragmented.  So you end up with a slower index, that ends up being really huge in memory and on disk due to the fragmentation.   Also on inserts of the uniqueidentifier you are more likely to end up with a page split on the index thus slowing your insert.  Generally uniqueidentifiers are bad news for indexes.

Comment: Good point. I'll remember. I think a compromision might be to have uniqueidentifier as a primary key and to build CLUSTERED index including not unique but sorting data columns in front of uniqueidentifier column. Then you have "physical" and useful order of data in table/pages.

Answer (score 2):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` in mysql, `IDENTITY` in SQL Server..

Answer (score 1):

`IDENTITY` in SQL Server

and if you need to get know what you new ID was while `INSERT`-ing data, use `OUTPUT` clause of `INSERT` statement - so the copy of new rows is put to table-type param.

If for some reason generating unique ID at SQL is not suitable for you, generate GUID's at your app - GUID has a very hight level of uniquness (but it's not guaranteed in fact). And SQL Server has dedicated GUID type for column - it's called `uniqueidentifier`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx